# How do i use bootstrap grid system adjusted to small screens with a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP genreted table which retrieve data and display the data in a table dynamically. It is essential to display  table data according to the table screen.

Here is my code:

```
echo "<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3'></div><div class='col-sm-6'><div class='table-responsive'><table border='0' class='table' >

<tr>
<td><img src='itempics/$i.jpg' width=200 height=200></td>
<td><h3>Product Details:</h3><b>Product:</b> ".$arr['pname']."<br>
<b>Item No:</b> ".$arr['itemno']."<br>
<b>Price:</b> ".$arr['price']."<br>
<b>Size:</b> ".$arr['size']."<br></td>

<td><h3>Buyer Details:</h3><b>Buyer:</b>  ".$arr['uname']."<br>
<b>Account No:</b> ".$arr['ac_no']."<br>
<b>Mobile No:</b> ".$arr['mob_no']."<br>
<b>Address:</b> ".$arr['add']."<br>
<b>Bank:</b> ".$arr['bank']."<br>
<b>City:</b> ".$arr['city']."<br>
<b>Order No:</b> ".$arr['order_no']."<br></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

";

Inside `td` class I use `.col-sm-3` and various bootstap methods but when the screen size is small it is not adopting according to the screen. I cant see the Buyer Details section in the table. Even I use responsive image class but it is use less in this case. All I want is when the screen size is small image is in one row Product details in next row and Buyer details in next row in the table. Can any one tell me how to properly do that...

Can I do it using div tag instead `<td>` tag?

Comment: use `table-responsive` class

Comment: yeap i already used it <div class="table responsive"><table class="table"> But it doesnt work actually.

Comment: bootstrap responsive table scrolls for with < 768px

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Here according to php code it generate a table with image of the item with product details and buyer details.My screen resolution is 1368*768 then all this image ,product details and buyer details in a one single row.But in a low resolution screen i can only display image with a product details.i cant see buyer details.When the small devices i want  this 3 items display in 3 rows actually.like class="col-sm-4" I tried adding those in to td  tag .But it doesnt work actually.

Answer (score 0):

use `col-xs-val` for widths <= 768px instead of `col-sm-val` in your generated html

Comment: That means do i have to edit the media query in bootstrap.min.css file

Answer (score 0):

You must use col-xs class as specified and for images use "img-responsive" class whereas for thumbnails you can use "img-thumbnail".

Replace your code with this:

```
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'><div class='col-xs-3'></div><div class='col-xs-6'><div class='table-responsive'><table border='0' class='table' >

<tr>
<td><img class="img-responsive" src='itempics/$i.jpg'></td>
<td><h3>Product Details:</h3><b>Product:</b> ".$arr['pname']."<br>
<b>Item No:</b> ".$arr['itemno']."<br>
<b>Price:</b> ".$arr['price']."<br>
<b>Size:</b> ".$arr['size']."<br></td>

<td><h3>Buyer Details:</h3><b>Buyer:</b>  ".$arr['uname']."<br>
<b>Account No:</b> ".$arr['ac_no']."<br>
<b>Mobile No:</b> ".$arr['mob_no']."<br>
<b>Address:</b> ".$arr['add']."<br>
<b>Bank:</b> ".$arr['bank']."<br>
<b>City:</b> ".$arr['city']."<br>
<b>Order No:</b> ".$arr['order_no']."<br></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-xs-3'></div>
</div>
</div>
```